# What's the correct way to get a backup from Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to copy a database from Azure to my local SQL Express 2014 instance.

My first try was to use the import wizard to create tables and import data but this creates tables without any constraint, identity specification, etc.

My next try was to create schema using a separated script and then use the wizard only for the data: now I have the problem that I have to manually enable identity insert and disable foreign keys. Even doing this I still get some errors so eventually abandoned this option.

Then I moved to [SQLAzureMW](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) and this generates some .dat files inside a folder (BCP I think) that I'm not certain how to easily import them in one shoot.

Could you please provide some guidence to get this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [Data Tier Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx). Using your Azure management portal you create the export (a `backpac` file) which can then be imported on-premise or into another Azure database.

- [Archive an Azure SQL database to a BACPAC file using the Azure Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-export/).
- [Import a BACPAC File to Create a New User Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710052.aspx)

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine right now to validate it but I remember not having `Import Data-tier Application` on menu. Could it be related with the fact that I'm using a SQL Express (2014)?

Comment: You need the latest Management Studio. I think it also works as PowerShell. I'm not sure though if the latest SSMS/PoSh can import into older engine versions (2014), nor if Express is actually supported (I don't have a machine to test either).